# SQL Server stored procedure need to declare scalar variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying this stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_Pager]
    @PageNo int = 1,
    @ItemsPerPage int = 2,
    @TotalRows int out
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  DECLARE
    @StartIdx int,
    @SQL nvarchar(max),  
    @SQL_Conditions nvarchar(max),  
    @EndIdx int

    IF @PageNo < 1 SET @PageNo = 1
    IF @ItemsPerPage < 1 SET @ItemsPerPage = 10

    SET @StartIdx = (@PageNo -1) * @ItemsPerPage + 1
    SET @EndIdx = (@StartIdx + @ItemsPerPage) - 1
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT FilePath
                FROM (
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS Row, * 
                      FROM  tblFiles ) AS tbl WHERE  Row >= ' 
                        + CONVERT(varchar(9), @StartIdx) + ' AND
                       Row <=  ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @EndIdx)
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @TotalRows=COUNT(*) FROM tblFiles' 
    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @query = @SQL, 
        @params = N'@TotalRows INT OUTPUT', 
        @TotalRows = @TotalRows OUTPUT 
END
```

it works well but I tried extending it with a view here is the code

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_Pager]
    @PageNo int = 1,
    @ItemsPerPage int = 2,
    @TotalRows int out,
    @fname varchar(50),
    @mname varchar(50),
    @lname varchar(50),
    @qfr varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  DECLARE
    @StartIdx int,
    @SQL nvarchar(max),  
    @SQL_Conditions nvarchar(max),  
    @EndIdx int

    IF @PageNo < 1 SET @PageNo = 1
    IF @ItemsPerPage < 1 SET @ItemsPerPage = 10

    SET @StartIdx = (@PageNo -1) * @ItemsPerPage + 1
    SET @EndIdx = (@StartIdx + @ItemsPerPage) - 1
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT path_front
                FROM (
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY fname) AS Row, * 
                      FROM  searcherview 
                      where (fname = @fname or @fname = '') and (mname = @mname or @mname = '') and (lname = @lname or @lname = '') and (qualifier = @qfr or @qfr = '')
                       ) AS tbl WHERE  Row >= ' 
                        + CONVERT(varchar(9), @StartIdx) + ' AND
                       Row <=  ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @EndIdx)
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @TotalRows=COUNT(*) FROM searcherview' 
    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @query = @SQL, 
        @params = N'@TotalRows INT OUTPUT', 
        @TotalRows = @TotalRows OUTPUT 
END
```

but when I try to execute the stored procedure an error is returning it says

> Must declare the scalar variable "@fname"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using variables in your `sp_executesql` you need to define them, as you are doing in your second `sp_executesql`

```
@params = N'@TotalRows INT OUTPUT', 
@TotalRows = @TotalRows OUTPUT
```

So you need to add

```
@params = N'@fname varchar(50), @mname varchar(50), @lname varchar(50), @qualifier varchar(10)',
@fname = @fname, @mname = @mname, @lname=@lname, @qualifier = @qfr
```

to your first `sp_executesql` call

Although why you're using dynamic SQL at all is not immediately apparent to me.

If you're using SQL 2012, you may be interested in the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` commands

Comment: i am using 2008 r2 i tried your suggestion but it says Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spx_Pager, Line 34
Incorrect syntax near '@params'.

Comment: @angelogogo You've probably missed out the comma after the SQL

Answer (score 1):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_Pager](
    @PageNo int = 1,
    @ItemsPerPage int = 2,
    @TotalRows int out,
    @fname varchar(50),
    @mname varchar(50),
    @lname varchar(50),
    @qfr varchar(10)
    )
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  DECLARE
    @StartIdx int,
    @SQL nvarchar(max),  
    @SQL_Conditions nvarchar(max),  
    @EndIdx int

    IF @PageNo < 1 SET @PageNo = 1
    IF @ItemsPerPage < 1 SET @ItemsPerPage = 10

    SET @StartIdx = (@PageNo -1) * @ItemsPerPage + 1
    SET @EndIdx = (@StartIdx + @ItemsPerPage) - 1
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT path_front
                FROM (
                SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY fname) AS Row, * 
                      FROM  searcherview 
                      where (fname = @firstname or @firstname = '') and (mname = @midname or @midname = '') and (lname = @lastname or @lastname = '') and (qualifier = @quali or @quali = '')
                       ) AS tbl WHERE  Row >= ' 
                        + CONVERT(varchar(9), @StartIdx) + ' AND
                       Row <=  ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @EndIdx)
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
    @params = N'@firstname varchar(50), @midname varchar(50), @lastname varchar(50), @quali varchar(10)',
    @firstname = @fname, @midname = @mname, @lastname=@lname, @quali = @qfr

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT @TotalRows=COUNT(*) FROM searcherview' 
    EXEC sp_executesql 
        @query = @SQL, 
        @params = N'@TotalRows INT OUTPUT', 
        @TotalRows = @TotalRows OUTPUT 
END
```

the final code and it work thanks to @podiluska